# Azure DevOps: git push fails with LFS with large file (>150MB)

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-lfs

Even though Azure DevOps docs mention that file size limit is 5GB even without LFS, all of my pushes with LFS file of size larger than ~100MB fail with this message that I find difficult to extract useful information from:

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 7.4 MB/s, done.
LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=<nil>) %!!(string=yyy.visualstudio.com) %!!(string=/engineering/_git/3d-printing/info/lfs/objects/07fe4f13daae6a98e27d50c6bb900850ec810f59bcf09b03ededfa02f38be225) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 413
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://yyy.visualstudio.com/engineering/_git/3d-printing'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Curious if anyone ran into similar situations before and what might be causing this issue? Thanks!

Pushing from different PCs running Windows 11 with Git 2.42.0 and and git LFS version 3.4.0 resulting in the same outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LFS: Client error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=) %!!(string=yyy.visualstudio.com) %) from HTTP 413

HTTP 413 is usually a proxy or any other networking/machine limitation.

To solve this issue, you can run the following command on your local machine.

```
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
```

On the other hand, you can also check if the presence of a local proxy server will affect git lfs.